# using LIKE with ZEND_DB

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I want to use a query which uses `LIKE` .. for e.g `select * from xxxx where zzzz LIKE 'a%';`
How can I do that using Zend DB?

I have already tried something like `$db->query('SELECT * FROM XXXX where zzzzz LIKE ?','\'' . $query .'%\'');` but it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You're double quoting. You don't need the escaped quotes around $query. Prepared statements will take care of that for you:

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM XXXX where zzzzz LIKE ?', '%' . $query .'%');
```

Comment: Thanks Mark .. sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$query = $user->select()->where('firstname LIKE ?', $uname.'%')->ORwhere('lastname LIKE ?', $_POST['lname'].'%')->ORwhere('emailid LIKE ?', $_POST['email'].'%');
    $userlist = $user->fetchAll($query);
```